# cakephp plugin delete data

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using user management plugin located at app/plugin/usermgmt/model/user.php and I have another model students located at app/model/student.php,so my question is  whenever i delete data from

users table, all data from student table should also get deleted.
I tried to use dependent=true ,but since user.php comes from plugin its not deleting data from students table.
Here is my model code at 
app/plugin/usermgmt/model/user.php

```
var $hasMany = array(
                'Student' => array(
                    'className' => 'Student',
                    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                    'dependent' => true,
                    'conditions' => '',
                    'fields' => '',
                    'order' => '',
                    'limit' => '',
                    'offset' => '',
                    'exclusive' => '',
                    'finderQuery' => '',
                    'counterQuery' => ''
            )
        );
```

and app/model/student.php as

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'Usermgmt.User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

so how can i delete data from both tables.
Thanks in advance

Comment: From where you are deleting the data?

Comment: Deleting from userscontroller located in plugin folder

Comment: try with exclusive => true

Comment: Get another plugin the one you're using has a pretty poor quality.